# Modify inline CSS of img tags using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to modify the inline CSS of img tags on the basis of the following critera:

1. Make no changes if it contains float:left or float:right
2. Else, add display:block.
3. Also, modify the margin CSS attributes. Change horizontal margin to auto and retain vertical margins.

So for example, if the code is as follows:

```
<img src="ex1.jpg" style="margin:5px 5px;float:left;" />
```

then no changes are to be made. But if the code is as follows:

```
<img src="ex2.jpg" style="margin:5px 175px;" />
```

then it should be modified to :

```
<img src="ex2.jpg" style="display:block;margin:5px auto;" />
```

or something like this :

```
<img src="ex3.jpg" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;" />
```

then it should be modified to :

```
<img src="ex3.jpg" style="display:block;margin-top:5px margin-left:auto;" />
```

**EDIT:**
The modifications to the img tags will have to be made in an HTML code obtained by my CMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: I am open to all kinds of solutions. And yeah I probably would need regex. But I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think it is a duplicate. For someone know regex, I think it is a simple and direct question.

Comment: @Quentin I am not asking a general 'how to parse HTML' question. I am asking a very specific question on how to modify inline CSS. I really don't think its a duplicate or the answers to that question help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

After I thought about it for a sec, it would be more helpful to see an example using a big blob of sample html rather than a nice list of img tags. See the updated code and output below.

The rules are pretty simple and can be run easily using preg_replace when needed and checks can be made using strpos to save the regex engine invocations. Let me know if you have any questions.

Output:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
    <img src="ex1.jpg" style="margin:5px 5px;float:left;" />
    <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
    <img src="ex2.jpg" style="display:block;margin:5px auto;" />
    <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
    <img src="ex3.jpg" style="display:block;margin-top:5px; margin-left:auto;" />
    <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
  </body>
<html>
```

Code:

```
<?php

// sample html blob
$sample_html = '
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
      <img src="ex1.jpg" style="margin:5px 5px;float:left;" />
      <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
      <img src="ex2.jpg" style="margin:5px 175px;" />
      <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
      <img src="ex3.jpg" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;" />
      <p> LOLOLOLOLOLOLOL </p>
    </body>
  <html>';

// grab all the matches for img tags and exit if there aren't any
if(!preg_match_all('/<img.*\/>/i', $sample_html, $matches))
  exit("Found no img tags that need fixing\n");

// check out all the image tags we found (stored in index 0)
print_r($matches);

// iterate through the results and run replaces where needed
foreach($matches[0] as $string){
  // keep this for later so that we can replace the original with the fixed one
  $original_string = $string;

  // no need to invoke the regex engine if we can just do a quick search. so here
  // we do nothing if it contains a float.
  if(false !=- strpos($string, 'float:')){
    continue;
  } 

  // inject the display:block if it doesn't already exist
  if(false === strpos($string, 'display:block;')){
    $string = preg_replace('/(<img.*style=")(.* \/>)/i', '$1display:block;$2', $string);
  }

  // preg_replace only replaces stuff when it matches a pattern so it's safe to
  // just run even if it wont do anything.

  // replace margin left if in margin:vert horiz; form
  $string = preg_replace('/(margin:[\s0-9]+px)\s[0-9]+px;/', "$1 auto;", $string);

  // replace margin-left value to auto
  $string = preg_replace('/(margin-left:).*;/', "$1auto;", $string);

  // now replace the original occurence in the html with the fix
  $sample_html = str_replace($original_string, $string, $sample_html);
}

// bam done
echo "{$sample_html}\n";

?>
```

Comment: ah. I was just about to ask how to go about it if an html document is used instead of a convenient array of img tags. I should have mentioned the same in the question, my bad. Let me run this and see if it works.

Comment: Heh. I figured that. I stared at the question for a second and thought "Yeah... my answer isn't really complete." I hope my edited answer helps you out. I realize that I have the html loaded into a string so if you are loading the html from a file you'll need to first load it into a string before you can use my example. Hope I at least lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. The HTML was in a string so that was not an issue. Thanks a lot for your help. The code and the comments were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern to match `<img/>` without having any `float` present in them:

```
<img(?![^<>]+?\bfloat\s*:\s*(?:left|right))[^<>]+>
```

**Explanation**

`<img(?![^<>]+?\bfloat\s*:\s*(?:left|right))[^<>]+>`

Match the characters `<img` literally `<img`. Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) `(?![^<>]+?\bfloat\s*:\s*(?:left|right))`. Match a single character NOT present in the list `<>` `[^<>]+?`. Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) `+?`
   Assert position at a word boundary `\b`. Match the characters `float` literally `float`. Match a single character that is a `whitespace character` (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) `\s*`. Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`. Match the character `:` literally `:`. Match a single character that is a `whitespace character` (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) `\s*`. Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`.   Match the regular expression below `(?:left|right)`. Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `left`. Match the characters `left` literally `left`. Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `right`. Match the characters `right` literally `right`. Match a single character NOT present in the list `<>` `[^<>]+`. Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`. Match the character `>` literally `>`. Then prepare your custom function to process the rest.

Comment: @Prakash could you please you revert your edits. It was much more readable in the original format.

Answer (score 0):

consider using `preg_match();`

here's the quick link to php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php. you can see examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty function from your definition:

```
function modify_img_css($html) {
    if (strpos($html, 'float:left') !== false || strpos($html, 'float:right') !== false) {
        return $html;
    }
    $html = str_replace('style="', 'style="display:block;', $html);
    if (strpos($html, 'margin-left:') !== false) {
        $html = preg_replace('/margin\-left:[^;]+;/', 'margin-left:auto;', $html);
    }
    if (strpos($html, 'margin:') !== false) {
        $html = preg_replace('/(margin:\s*\S+\s+)\S+;/', '\1auto;', $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```